# Camera Viewport Is locked to corner of screen, can't undo

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am extremely new to Blender and have been following some tutorials on how to make a simple glass cup. However, anytime I add a camera and go in to view the render and get my shot aligned right, my camera is locked to the upper left hand side no matter what I do and I can't seem to get the whole camera in the actual viewport.

[image]

The full camera isn't in view, and I can't adjust it and nothing I search for online brings back any helpful results.

Comment: There already is an answer by @L0Lock although what he mentions are the usual simple things I would try - if it helps, then I would highly recommend learning Blender's viewport navigation. If it doesn't, it might be helpful to know what "no matter what I do" in your question actually means - what exactly have you done so far that did not work?

Answer (score 2):

Hold down <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and use your <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to drag it back to where you want.

Or press <kbd>Home</kbd> to center the camera view to its bounds. You can also access this operator from the menu View ► Camera ► Frame Camera Bounds.